# Multiple Objects in an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops

im not really into jQuery, but i need to learn it so i can realize some Projects im working on.

I use Datatables with the select-Extension to multiselect table-rows. Afterwards i need to work with the values of this rows in php. All of that allready works like a charm, problem is i can only use one table within a form. That means i only get the results of the first table with the class "table_select" into an $_POST-Variable.

I tried to change the jQuery-Code to iterate over all objects with this class, so i made an array and tried to push this Array with [Array.length], still i only get values in Array[0].

What am i doing wrong?

```
    var table = [];

table[table.length] =  $('.table_select').DataTable( {
    'initComplete': function(){
    var api = this.api();
     api
        .rows()
            .every(function(){
           var data = this.data();
           if(data[1] === '1'){
              api.cells(this.index(), 0).checkboxes.select();
           }
        });
    },
    order: [[2, "asc"]],
    paging:false,
    info:false,
    filter:false,
    language: {
        "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json",
    },
    columns: [
        null,
        { "visible": false},
        null
    ],
    'columnDefs': [{
        'targets': 0,
        'checkboxes': {
            'selectRow': true,
            'selectAll': false
        }
    }],
    select: {
        style: 'multi'
    }
}); 
flen = table.length;
```

flen is allways "1" in this case, even if i have 4 Tabes with the "table_select"-Class.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit:

I changed the code based on the comments to:

```
table =  $('.table_select').DataTable( {
    'initComplete': function(){
    var api = this.api();
     api
        .rows()
            .every(function(){
           var data = this.data();
           if(data[1] === '1'){
              api.cells(this.index(), 0).checkboxes.select();
           }
        });
    },
    order: [[2, "asc"]],
    paging:false,
    info:false,
    filter:false,
    language: {
        "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json",
    },
    columns: [
        null,
        { "visible": false},
        null
    ],
    'columnDefs': [{
        'targets': 0,
        'checkboxes': {
            'selectRow': true,
            'selectAll': false
        }
    }],
    select: {
        style: 'multi'
    }
}); 

alert(table.length);
```

The alert in this case i allways "0".

Edit2: Example jsfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/tu59s6Ls](http://jsfiddle.net/tu59s6Ls)

Answer (score 0):

let me explain what you are doing

```
var table = [];  // this is setting length 0 as no value


table[table.length] = ... // here you are setting table[0] = ...
```

this means you are setting the entire value at index 0. so what ever oblect is coming from jQuery datatable its set to index 0 so the length of table is always 1

You need to set the entire value in table variable not at the index 0

```
table =  ...
```

Comment: ok, i understand what you mean, i missunderstood the description in http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp with "pushing Arrays".

I need to have every element (exact: table) with the "table_select"-class to be in an Array, so if i have 4 tables i need to have "table[0]", "table[1]", "table[2]", "table[3]". How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `table` variable is array, and in the first position of the array (table[0]) you put a reference to the `DataTable`'s elements. You might have 4 elements with the `table_select` class, but you save the reference to them in the first item (and not in the variable).

So actually - `table[0].length` == 4, but `table.length` == 0.

You can use

```
table[0].lenght
```

**or**

```
table = $('.table_select').DataTable
```

(without the array you have there).

Comment: i tried to use

`table = $('.table_select').DataTable`

flen in this case is allways "0"

Comment: Can you provide a working example? (jsfiddle or something). The `datatable` function should return a jquery object with elements it applied to (and if you really have 4 tables the length there should be 4).

Comment: What happen if you run `alert($('.table_select').length)` ?

Comment: `alert($('.table_select').length)` gives back 4  
Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tu59s6Ls/  
Maybe its because i read `$('.table_select').DataTable` ?

Answer (score 0):

DataTable does not return, when instantiated, the data you want.

You can access it with <s>context</s> `data()`

So when instantiate the datatable, save it to a variable, then access that variable <s>.context</s> **.data()** property

**edit**

use `.data()` instead of *context*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let datatable = $('.table_select').DataTable({
    'initComplete': function() {
      var api = this.api();
      api
        .rows()
        .every(function() {
          var data = this.data();
          if (data[1] === '1') {
            api.cells(this.index(), 0).checkboxes.select();
          }
        });
    },
    order: [
      [2, "asc"]
    ],
    paging: false,
    info: false,
    filter: false,
    language: {
      "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json",
    },
    columns: [
      null, {
        "visible": false
      },
      null
    ],
    'columnDefs': [{
      'targets': 0,
      'checkboxes': {
        'selectRow': true,
        'selectAll': false
      }
    }],
    select: {
      style: 'multi'
    }
  });

  let table = datatable.data();

  alert(table.length);
  alert($('.table_select').length);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jszip-2.5.0/pdfmake-0.1.18/dt-1.10.12/b-1.2.2/b-colvis-1.2.2/b-flash-1.2.2/b-html5-1.2.2/b-print-1.2.2/fh-3.1.2/se-1.2.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jszip-2.5.0/pdfmake-0.1.18/dt-1.10.12/b-1.2.2/b-colvis-1.2.2/b-flash-1.2.2/b-html5-1.2.2/b-print-1.2.2/fh-3.1.2/se-1.2.0/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form id="form_login" action="" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left select_table_form" method="post">
  <table class="table table_select table-hover display" width="100%;" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
        </th>
        <th>
        </th>
        <th>
          Test
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Test
        </td>
        <td>
          Test
        </td>
        <td>
          Value 1
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table table_select table-hover display" width="100%;" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
        </th>
        <th>
        </th>
        <th>
          Test
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Test
        </td>
        <td>
          Test
        </td>
        <td>
          Value 1
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table table_select table-hover display" width="100%;" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
        </th>
        <th>
        </th>
        <th>
          Test
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Test
        </td>
        <td>
          Test
        </td>
        <td>
          Value 1
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table table_select table-hover display" width="100%;" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
        </th>
        <th>
        </th>
        <th>
          Test
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Test
        </td>
        <td>
          Test
        </td>
        <td>
          Value 1
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tipp.
I now get 4 Objects in the Array, but it seems like i lose the relevant data in this step: [https://jsfiddle.net/tu59s6Ls/1/]  
Based on this script [http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/] i try to get the values of all selected rows. But if i dump the objects like in the jsfiddle there seems to be no data for this anymore.

Comment: @Daniel just updated it. use .data() as described above

Comment: @GuiServ Just update my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tu59s6Ls/2/  
I get the data from the tables, but i don't get the value '1' when the row is selected, just the inital set values are set on '1'. Also i only got them in jQuery while i need them in a $_POST-Variable to work with the result in php.
After submitting i only get the selected rows from the first table in the form, the others are ignored. I think i have to iterate over every object with the added code.  
Thanks for all the effort, i hope i express myself at least understandable  
Btw:How can i get jsfiddle to work with submit?